# What does the "simplify" option when exporting to FBX?

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

While exporting a FBX, I noticed that there is a 'simplify' option:

[image]

Unfortunately, the [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html#bake-animation) lacks on detail about that feature and the tooltip just says something like *"How much to simplify baked value"*, which is not helpful:

> ...
> Sampling Rate 
> TODO.
> Simplify 
> TODO. 
> ...

I'd like to know what it actually does and when to use this option. The default value is `1` for me. Should I just set it `0` to be safe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FBX exporter bakes animations at the given sampling rate. Basically you get one keyframe for every frame. Of course if the original curve wasn't changing over a particular range of time, baking gets you a bunch of duplicate keyframes. "Simplify" cleans these up by deleting keyframes that differ very little from the last keyframe. This saves space in the FBX file.

The simplify option is a factor that controls how much two keyframes are allowed to differ before they are considered different for the purpose of "simplify". With the default factor of 1.0, this is a relative difference of 0.01% or (for numbers close to zero) an absolute difference of 0.0001.

The relevant function to read is [`AnimationCurveNodeWrapper.simplify`](https://github.com/sobotka/blender-addons/blob/b1226da66a49a524ee17053c8f43d356597b18f4/io_scene_fbx/fbx_utils.py#L777).

I'd leave it as the default value, but you can see if using 0.0 will fix it if you have some kind of problem with animations.